# Combine anchor, url variable and toggle visibility

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, anchor

I am using this code to toggle visibility

```
var prevId;

function toggle_visibility(id) {
   if(prevId){
      $("#"+prevId).slideToggle("slow");
   }
   var e = document.getElementById(id);

      $(e).slideToggle("slow");
   prevId = id;

}
```

On the div that appears I am using this to display the data from the database

```
<?php 
include"scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

$news="";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `news` 
ORDER BY date DESC"); 
$newsCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($newsCount>0) {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id=$row["id"];
        $title=$row["title"];
        $text=$row["text"];
        $date=$row["date"];
        $news.=' <table width="800" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:150px;">' . $date . '</td>
    <td style="width:600px; overflow:hidden;"><a href="?id=' . $id . '#" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'news_det\');" style="color:#b19057;" >' . $title . '</a></td>
    <td style="width:50px"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'news_det\');" style="color:#000;">...more</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
';
    }

}else {
    $news="No news available yet";
}

?>
```

The problem is that if i click on this link

```
<a href="?id=' . $id . '#" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'news_det\');" style="color:#b19057;" >' . $title . '</a>
```

the toggle starts but interrupts on the first click, but works on the second.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is `news_det` in your code?

Comment: news_det is the hidden div that sould become visible onclick

Comment: can you make working demo of your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ with some dummy data

Comment: you can see it here newsite2.reload-it.gr

Comment: so what I guess you want to do is showing detail on click of title and hiding detail again on click of NEWS tab and showing list again, right?

Comment: just show the details on click of the title would be sufficient. unfortunately it is not working on first click, but on the second. I think that the problem is that the pages refreshes on the first click

Comment: yes your problem is page being refreshed so just change your href="?id=' . $id . '#" to href="#id=' . $id . '"

Comment: already tried that. when I do that, i get no data at all.just the toggle effect working.

Comment: are you getting data from server call?

Comment: the url looks like that after the click." index.php#id=2 " but cant get the data with $_GET

Comment: so you can add ? as href="#?id='.$id.'", but are you getting data everytime my requesting to server?

Comment: when the # is in front i dont get data. when then # is in the end i get data, but the page refreshes so i cant display them on first click

Comment: with this href="?id=' . $id . '#" i get the data but the page refreshes so the toggle isnt working and with this href="#?id=' . $id . '" the toggle is working but i cant get the data!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two recommendation for your code to solve your problem

**One Way**

Change your JavaScript function to something like this

```
var prevId;

function toggle_visibility(id, newsId) {
    if (prevId) {
        $("#"+prevId).slideToggle("slow");
    }
    $("#"+id).slideToggle("slow");
    if (id=="news_det" && newsId!=undefined) {
        var val=$("#det_"+newsId).val();
        $('#news_detDiv').html(val);//Where you are putting text that div id
    }
    prevId = id;
    return false;
}
```

Change your html snippet from `$news` variable to this

```
$news.='<table width="800" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:150px;">' . $date . '</td>
        <td style="width:600px; overflow:hidden;"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'news_det\', '.$id.');" style="color:#b19057;">' . $title . '</a></td>
        <td style="width:50px"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'news_det\', '.$id.');" style="color:#000;">...more</a></td>
        <input type="hidden" value="'.$text.'" id="det_'.$id.'">
    </tr>
</table>';
```

In this way you will save your server call, since you will be storing all your text in your page only and you will always see relevant post data on click of title & more. Moreover your effect will also work.

**Second Way**

You should use JQuery AJAX call on click of **title** & **more** to get data from server instead of going with refreshing page.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: could you provide also a solution with AJAX??? I have never tried coding with AJAX before, so I wouldnt know where to start. Thank you for your time.. @TheMohanAhuja

Comment: <a  href="#" onclick="newsdata(\'news_detx1\','.$id.');" style="color:#b19057;">' . $title . '</a> function newsdata(id, currid) {
 
      
   $("#news_exp").slideUp("slow");
   $("#news_detx1").slideDown("slow");
    $("#news_detx1").load( "test.php?id="+currid ); 
   


return false;
} works great!!!